# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^2+n-1}{3n^2+1}=\frac{1}{3}$ using the definition

Tags: calculus, limits

> Prove $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^2+n-1}{3n^2+1}=\frac{1}{3}$$ using the definition.

Let there be $\varepsilon>0$ we need to find $N<n$ such that $\Big|\frac{n^2+n-1}{3n^2+1}-\frac{1}{3}$$
\Big|<\varepsilon$

$$\left|\frac{n^2+n-1}{3n^2+1}-\frac{1}{3}
\right|=\left|\frac{3n^2+3n-3-3n^2-1}{9n^2+3}
\right|=\left|\frac{3n-4}{9n^2+3}\right|$$

What should I do next, can I say that because $n\to \infty$ we can neglect $-4$ and $3$ from the expression?

Comment: In the second term it should be $...-3n^2-1$ leading to $3n-4$ in the numerator.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks edited

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\frac{n-3}{3n^2+1}\leq \frac{1}{3n}$

Answer (score 1):

$|\frac{3n-4}{9n^2+3}|<\frac{3n}{9n^2}=\frac{1}{3n}\leq\frac{1}{3N}<\epsilon$ whenever $n\geq N>\frac{1}{3\epsilon}$